# qt combobox readable but editable

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

I have at QComboBox some items (added by program - it is a lot added items (about 1000))

So i make combobox editable -> then it is simple to find a correct item. (For example if i want to find item called "My Example" i write in combobox "MY" and i get items which starts from "MY" )

But when i write somethink other than it is in combobox, combobox add this item.

I dont want it, i want only to:

1. Can select only ITEMS added by Program
2. Block adding custom items
3. When i write something like "MY" but dont select item "My Example" because there is "My Example","My Example2"

And press push button to accept my choice - then how to check that i choice item from items added by Program not written and not finished by User?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set these QComboBox properties to the following:
1. Set `setEditable` to `true`.
2. Set `insertPolicy` to `NoInsert`.
3. Set `currentIndex` to `-1` to make it empty at start.

Then process `currentIndexChanged` signal which will be sent only when a certain item from the list is chosen.